# What is the point of PCA

Tags: pca

The only reason I can think of to use PCA is to use it basically the same way you use exploratory factor analysis. It can validate for us that questions in a survey load onto principal components the way you would expect.

I can't think of a way to use it other than that. My understanding is that PCA is basically worthless if you are trying to predict something. I can't use PCA for feature selection, meaning that I can't use PCA to tell me which of my original columns to use in a model. I also can't use the newly-created principal component scores in a predictive model.

Given that, even if I can use PCA to choose a small number of principal components that capture a lot of variance, what's the point? Would love a specific example or two, beyond using it as a substitute for CFA and EFA in academia.

Comment: You can pick, say, $5$ principal components that are derived from your $p\ge 5$ original features and then run a regression on those $5$ principal components, yet your post makes it sound like you think this cannot be done. Why do you think that?

Comment: There are **a lot** of relevant posts on site. [Look through some](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=uses%20of%20pca) of the highest-voted ones.

Comment: PCA is a key ingredient in the majority of dimension-reduction methods.  It is a key tool for the analysis of any set of points in a Euclidean space.